# postgresql subquery count within a larger context

Tags: postgresql, subquery

I have the following query:

```
 SELECT sum(p.price) as "totalPurchase", sum(s.price) as "totalSale", sum(er.price) as          
 "totalRet", v.name as "vendor"
 FROM "Esns" e
 JOIN "EsnsPurchaseOrderItems" ep on ep."EsnId" = e.id
 JOIN "PurchaseOrderItems" p on ep."PurchaseOrderItemId"= p.id
 JOIN "PurchaseOrders" po on p."PurchaseOrderId" = po.id
 JOIN "Vendors" v on po."VendorId" = v.id
 LEFT OUTER JOIN "EsnsSalesOrderItems" es on es."EsnId" = e.id
 LEFT OUTER JOIN "SalesOrderItems" s on es."SalesOrderItemId" = s.id
 LEFT OUTER JOIN "EsnsRmas" er on er."EsnId" = e.id
 GROUP BY v.id
```

However, i want to also count all e.id that are organized by the above join along with the field e."inStock" = true.

Comment: if i simply do this (select count(e.*) where e."inStock" 
) as "inStock"-- it gives me the correct info but for some reason splits up the results incorrectly, meaning where there was one line items with 50,000 in sales there are now two with 25,000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  sum(p.price) as "totalPurchase", 
        sum(s.price) as "totalSale", 
        sum(er.price) as "totalRet", 
        v.name as "vendor",
        sum(CASE WHEN e."inStock" = true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "totalInStock"
FROM    .....
GROUP   BY ....
```

OR

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN e."inStock" = true THEN 1 END) as "totalInStock"
```

Comment: this has the same problem i mention in my above comment. Incorrectly splitting up the rows

Comment: sorry i had forgotten to include that bit of info in my original comment